# how to merge two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to merge objects here and would like to convert to JSON object. I would like to create an object array and add objects in to it. In this example i would like to create ConsData object array and add each dataset in to it.

```
I would like the data to be like
[
{

    "name":"aaa_aaaurf",
    "region":"F&R",
    "checkins":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,3],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]],
    "teamsize":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,1],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]],
    "Checkintimes":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,184],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]
},
{

    "name":"aaa_accessservices",
    "region":"F&R",
    "checkins":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,27],[12,12]],
    "teamsize":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,11],[12,11]],
    "Checkintimes":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,10],[12,12]]
}]

var ConsData = {};
var MergeData = {};


 for(var x=0;x<dataset.length;x++)
 {

       repository = dataset[x].repository;
        sbu = dataset[x].BusinessUnit
        checkinsarray.push([index, dataset[x].AvgCheckinCount]);
        teamsizearray.push([index, dataset[x].TeamSize]);
        checkintimesarray.push([index, dataset[x].MeanBuildTimeHrs]);

        ConsData["name"] = repository;
        ConsData["region"] = sbu;
        ConsData["checkins"] = checkinsarray;
        ConsData["teamsize"] = teamsizearray;
        ConsData["Checkintimes"] = checkintimesarray;
}
```

following is the data contained in dataset(fetched from csv file):

```
repository,month,year,MeanBuildTimeHrs,AvgCheckinCount,TeamSize,BusinessUnit
aaa_aaaurf,1,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,2,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,3,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,4,2013,184,3,3,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,5,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,6,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,7,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,8,2013,0,3,1,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,9,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,10,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,11,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
aaa_aaaurf,12,2013,0,0,0,Financial&Risk
cCG_tzz,1,2013,5,3,100,Financial&Risk
cCG_tzz,2,2013,8,5,80,Financial&Risk
aCG_txz,1,2013,12,3,70,Financial&Risk
GCG_txz,1,2013,21,3,50,Financial&Risk
GCG_txz,2,2013,12,3,70,Financial&Risk
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you actually want to merge. You're currently modifying `ConsData` multiple times. Do you want an array of objects like `[{"name": repository, "region": sbu, ..}]` as result? Also, your first paragraph sounds like a wish list for Christmas.

Comment: hi Zeta, I have added the format of the data to be merged. Sorry it is similar as the one specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataArray = [], i;

for(i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++)
{
    dataArray.push({
        "name":         dataset[x].repository,
        "region":       dataset[x].BusinessUnit,
        "checkins":     [index, dataset[x].AvgCheckinCount],
        "teamsize":     [index, dataset[x].TeamSize],
        "Checkintimes": [index, dataset[x].MeanBuildTimeHrs]
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
```

You need to use a *new* object for every element in your array. Objects are stored by *reference*, and variables have *function* scope.

After having a look at your other questions, I recommend you to have a look at the [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#merge)?

```
var names = {
  'characters': [
    { 'name': 'barney' },
    { 'name': 'fred' }
  ]
};

var ages = {
  'characters': [
    { 'age': 36 },
    { 'age': 40 }
  ]
};

_.merge(names, ages);
// → { 'characters': [{ 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'name': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }

var food = {
  'fruits': ['apple'],
  'vegetables': ['beet']
};

var otherFood = {
  'fruits': ['banana'],
  'vegetables': ['carrot']
};

_.merge(food, otherFood, function(a, b) {
  return _.isArray(a) ? a.concat(b) : undefined;
});
// → { 'fruits': ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetables': ['beet', 'carrot] }
```

Comment: Actually, I guess he doesn't want to merge two objects, but instead create a list/array of objects. Looking at his previous question, he misses to create a new object and overrides the same `ConsData` all the time.

Comment: @zeta but this answer needs to be here for anyone who is trying to figure out "how to merge objects in javascript".

Comment: Initially, i created an object and then using Jquery.extend tried to merge another object. However if i had to merge multiple objects i was having an issue. That's why i posted. However i got the issue resolved through zet. Instead of merging multiple objects, created alist of objects and added the same.