# How to concatenate or merge two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two array variables: `var1` and `var2`.

```
$scope.var1 = {
"0":{"subjectId":"1","subjectShortName":"English","subjectCode":null,"IsSelected":true},
"1":{"subjectId":"2","subjectShortName":"Hindi","subjectCode":null,"IsSelected":true}
};

$scope.var2 = {"classId":"3","typeOfSubject":"main"}
```

How I can merge or concatenate these two arrays to get the kind of array below? Basically I want to add all `subjectId` as Key to second array.

```
$scope.var2 = {"classId":"3","typeOfSubject":"main", "subjectId":"{1,2}"}
```

Comment: Just a general comment: I don't see a single array in your code right now.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but just to understand from who knows more than me. What a kind of objects is the first var ? It seems an object with inside other two objects... I knew the array of objects (like JSON), but this one is quite differente. Could someone explain ? Or it's just something like a string used only by angularjs ?

Comment: What @Sirko is saying is that those are objects.

Comment: @Gianca. The first var is an object with two properties. The value of those two properties are also objects.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. what is the resulting subjectId? Is it an array of integers?

Comment: @Drumbeg thank you, at first I was a little bit confused. Now it's clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is not clear. Anyway following your request here it is. It will add the subjectIds of `var1` into `var2` as a list of integers.

```
var subjectIds = [];
for(var k in $scope.var1) {
   subjectIds.push(parseInt($scope.var1[k].subjectId));
}
$scope.var2.subjectId = subjectIds.join(', ');
```

Results into

```
{ classId: '3', typeOfSubject: 'main', subjectId: "1, 2" }
```

Comment: can it be SubjectId:"1,2' ? String instead of array. For example { classId: '3', typeOfSubject: 'main', subjectId: ' 1, 2 ' }

Answer (score 2):

In your exemple you are using objects not arrays.
But I leave here how to join two objects.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

In your case:

```
$scope.new_var = angular.extend({}, $scope.var1, $scope.var2)
```

.

If you intend to use array I do not know a native function in angularjs.

You can use **jquery** > http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/

Or **javascript**

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

Comment: It does not look like this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to merge these objects so the result looks like:

```
{
    "classId": "3", 
    "typeOfSubject": "main", 
    "subjectId": {
        "1": {"subjectId": "1", "subjectShortName": "English", ...}
        "2": {"subjectId": "2", "subjectShortName": "Hindi", ...}
    }
}
```

This doesn't require any angular support to accomplish, but you can use [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to iterate your `var1` object easily:

```
$scope.var2.subjectId = {};

angular.forEach($scope.var1, function(subject){
    this[subject.subjectId] = subject;
}, $scope.var2.subjectId); //set "this" to the member of var2 we're populating
```

Comment: want like this ... {
    "classId": "3", 
    "typeOfSubject": "main", 
    "subjectId": "1,2"
    }

Comment: It should be obvious that you can change the forEach callback function to whatever you need for your specific case. If you want a comma separated string, do `this.push(subject.subjectId)` and afterwards use array join.

Answer (score 0):

These are objects, not array.. note that array have this `[]` brackets, while objects are `{}` just like your code.. in this case you want to join a new object into your constructed object..

Your problem has already been solved in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993199/how-to-merge-two-objects-in-javascript)

But if you wish to see a smaller code.. would be using `extends` function in `AngularJS` according to the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
angular.extends(yourObject, objectToJoin, ...);
```

note that this function is inherited from `jQuery` and you can check the `jQuery` docs version in [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)